# How can I make my simple Haskell function recursive?

Tags: haskell

This is my function:

```
rotatebyone :: [Int] -> [Int]
rotatebyone [] = []
rotatebyone (x:xs) = ((tail (x:xs)) ++ (take 1 (x:xs)))

rotatebyn :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
rotatebyn n [] = []
rotatebyn 1 (x:xs) = rotatebyone (x:xs) 
rotatebyn 2 (x:xs) = (rotatebyone (rotatebyone (x:xs)))
```

I want my function to repeat itself for n-times. I guess you do this with guardians or the "while" operator, but I don't know quite how. The goal is to rotate elements of a integer-list n-times.

This was my failed approach:

```
rota :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
rota n (x:xs) = rotatebyone (x:xs)
                where
                rota n
                    | n > 1 = rota (n - 1)
                    | otherwise = rotatebyone (x:xs)
```

Comment: But it doesn't help me specifically for my example. I still don't know the answer.

Comment: But your question is the same as the linked question. Is there some part of the answer that you don't understand?

Comment: So I should do it with iterate?

Comment: No, you should not do it with `iterate`, or anything of the like. Doing the same thing `n` times is is absolutely the wrong way to rotate a list!

Comment: So how should I do it then?

Comment: @Paddy369, look at arguments and results. Can you think of another way to accomplish that? Your approach will be very inefficient (O (n * k)), where you rotate a list of length k n times. You can do it in O (k).

Comment: I don't get it :/

Comment: Haskell has no `while` *operator*.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rotate multiple places by rotating once and doing that repeatedly. Let's look at a slightly cleaner version of your single rotation to see why:

```
rotateLeft1 :: [a] -> [a]
rotateLeft1 [] = []
rotateLeft1 (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```

The problem is that `p ++ q` takes time linear in the length of `p`. You're doing that once for each rotation step, which wastes a lot of time. Let's look at it differently, with an example.

```
rotateLeft 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
-- split the list
([1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8])
-- swap the pieces
([4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3])
-- Append
[4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3]
```

There's one tricky bit left: what if I rotate a list by a number greater than its length? I'll let you give that a go yourself.

Comment: If I rotate it for example seven times it would be the same as I would rotate it 1 time with 6 elements.So basically  I just divide the amount of rotations I do by n-elements and my remainder will be the total amount of rotations. For example if I want to rotate the list 23 times with 6 elements, then I do 23/6= 3 mod 5 -> So 5 rotations. But I still don't know how to make it recursive, the efficiency is not so important for me.

Comment: @Paddy369, what do you mean, "make it recursive"?

Comment: I mean that it won't rotate just once, but rather 3, or 4 times.

Comment: My problem I have that I don't know what to write in Haskell so the rotation won't be only once. Currently your rotateLeft1 function only rotates once, so my question is, how do I write the rotateLeft function.

Comment: @Paddy369, I outlined the procedure I suggest for writing `rotateLeft`, which does *not* involve any calls to `rotateLeft1`. What specific aspect do you find hard to understand?

Comment: The part where I split the list. How do I write that?

Comment: @Paddy369, look up `splitAt`.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first clean up the `rotatebyone` function:

```
rotatebyone :: [Int] -> [Int]
rotatebyone [] = []
rotatebyone (x:xs) = ((tail (x:xs)) ++ (take 1 (x:xs)))
```

Here you call `tail` on `(x:xs)` but that is quite weird, since we already have a tail: `xs`. So we can replace `tail (x:xs)` with `xs`.

The same holds for `take 1 (x:xs)`. This will construct a list with the head of the list, so `[x]`. So we can clean up the code to:

```
rotatebyone :: [Int] -> [Int]
rotatebyone [] = []
rotatebyone (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```

Furthermore your function only works on lists of type `Int` (it has signature `[Int] -> [Int]`). We can however rotate lists by one regardless the type of elements these lists hold, so we can write it as:

```
rotatebyone :: [a] -> [a]
rotatebyone [] = []
rotatebyone (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```

Now we can look for a way to rotate `n` times with:

```
rotatebyn :: Int ->[a] -> [a]
rotatebyn ...
```

In case we wish to rotate over zero places, then the list remains the same, so as a base case we can write:

```
rotatebyn 0 l = l
```

and in case we want to rotate over one or more places, we can rotate over one place by the `rotatebyone` function, and then rotate this result another `n-1` times:

```
rotatebyn n l = rotatebyn (n-1) (rotateone n)
```

or these together:

```
rotatebyn :: Int ->[a] -> [a]
rotatebyn 0 l = l
rotatebyn n l = rotatebyn (n-1) (rotateone n)
```

But the above is, like [@dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47257181/67579) says not efficient: it takes *O(n)* time to rotate a list, if we need to do this *k* times, the time complexity is thus *O(n k)*.

Note furthermore that the above function only works in case `n` is greater than or equal to zero.